# Alternative to lookbehind regex

Tags: regex

Unfortunately, Firefox does not support lookbehind regex yet and I was not able to rewrite it.

Scenario: Split string by `/` but not the `/` after "abc".

regex: `/(?<!abc)\//g`
example text: `test/abc/foo`

Desired outcome: only the first  not the `/` after abc.

Is it possible to rewrite to regex or should I look for workaround without regex?

Comment: for which engine?

Comment: Try `your_string.match(/(?:abc\/|[^\/])+/g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a lookbehind, you cannot use a splitting approach that easily.

You may *match* any char other than `/` or `abc/` substring:

```
/(?:abc\/|[^\/])+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NmCU6n/1)

The pattern means:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `abc\/` - a lieral `abc/` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\/]` - any char other than `/`
- `)+` - 1 or more repetitions.

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
   "test/abc/foo".match(/(?:abc\/|[^\/])+/g)
)
```